# How to translate static slug in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls, slug

Hello I am trying to develop a multilanguage website in Django.
I am using django-modeltranslation for this.

I can change the dynamic slugs via Django admin this is fine.
But how can i change the static slug?

For example I am talking about this:

```
mydomain.com/services/my-dynamic-service
```

Here is services is static slug. But when I change the language of website, I want to change /services/ slug to new slug meaning /services/ from the language I switch.